# Acción al mantener presionado un botón en Unity5 c#

Tags: c#, botón, unity, unity2d

Se necesita generar una acción al mantener presionado un botón en unity5 , este botón es creado dentro de un Canvas UI , el cual al mantenerse presionado necesita llamar a un método generado en un scrip.

El problema se genera debido a que solo realiza la acción al momento de presionarlo y no mientras éste está presionado

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato y terminará cerrada

Comment: Es decir que has intentado?, Que errores se te han presentado?

Comment: Hola @BeTam, he editado la consulta espero haber sido específico . Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución será utilizando el método [OnPointerDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/es/530/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.OnPointerDown.html). Tendremos que añadir las librerías de EventSystem y Events , e incluyendo los métodos IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler.

Generaremos una condición dentro del método Update consultando si el botón esta siendo presionado y de esa manera invocaremos la acción deseada.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class PressedButton : MonoBehaviour,  IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{

    public UnityEvent OnHold;
    bool OnPressed;

    public void OnPointerDown( PointerEventData eventData )
    {
        OnPressed = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerUp( PointerEventData eventData )
    {
        OnPressed = false;
    }
    

    void Update ()
    {
        if (OnPressed)
        {
            OnHold.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Este script lo agregaremos al objeto deseado, incorporando acción deseada. Como en el siguiente ejemplo es un scrip llamando a un metodo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]